# PostgreSQL, R: Multiply all rows of table to create Panel-data (time-series)

Tags: r, postgresql, panel-data

I have a table `buildings` with 3.2 million rows. I need to expand this table to 11 different periods, to handle it as [(balanced) Paneldata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data). This means that for every object there are 11 different years (from 2000-2010) to observate. The periods should be called:

```
2000
2001
...
2009
2010
```

#### TABLE DEFINITIONS

```
CREATE TABLE public.buildings
(
  gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('buildings_gid_seq'::regclass),
  osm_id character varying(11),
  name character varying(48),
  type character varying(16),
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
  centroid geometry(Point,4326),
  gembez character varying(50),
  gemname character varying(50),
  krsbez character varying(50),
  krsname character varying(50),
  pv boolean,
  gr smallint,
  capac double precision,
  instdate date,
  pvid integer,
  dist double precision,
  gemewz integer,
  n500 integer,
  ibase double precision,
  popden integer,
  instp smallint,
  b2000 double precision,
  b2001 double precision,
  b2002 double precision,
  b2003 double precision,
  b2004 double precision,
  b2005 double precision,
  b2006 double precision,
  b2007 double precision,
  b2008 double precision,
  b2009 double precision,
  b2010 double precision,
  ibase_id integer[],
  ibase_dist integer[],
  CONSTRAINT buildings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.buildings
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE INDEX build_centroid_gix
  ON public.buildings
  USING gist
  (st_transform(centroid, 31467));

CREATE INDEX buildings_geom_idx
  ON public.buildings
  USING gist
  (geom);
```

I want to use the data for a regression analysis in *R*.

`ibase_id` is an array of `gid`. 
`ibase_dist` is an related array with the distances of the `gid`'s to the obejct. The length of the two arrays is always the same.

The `gid`'s in the array belong to records of `buildings`, which are within a Radius of 500m around the `centroid`,the center of the obeject, AND have pv=TRUE (which implies that `dist`,`instdate`,`instp`,`capac`&`pvid` are `NOT NULL`).

```
SELECT a.gid AS buildid, array_agg(b.gid) AS ibase_id, array_agg(round(ST_Distance(ST_Transform(a.centroid, 31467), ST_Transform(b.centroid, 31467))::integer)) AS ibase_dist
  FROM buildings a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM buildings WHERE pv=TRUE) AS b ON ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(a.centroid, 31467), ST_Transform(b.centroid, 31467), 500.0)
      AND a.gid <> b.gid
  GROUP BY a.gid
```

**Example:**

`ibase_id: {3075528,409073,322311,226643,833798,322344,226609}`;

`ibase_dist {290,293,398,494,411,381,384}`

```
UPDATE buildings
SET ibase=SUM(1/s)
FROM unnest(SELECT ibasedist FROM buildings WHERE (SELECT instp 
       FROM buildings 
       WHERE gid IN unnest(ibase_id))<year) s
```

For each period, only the entrys of the arrays shall be considered, whose years were BEFORE the observated period of the panel-data. **(The query above does not work, yet, because I need to concastenate the arrays first)** Right now, the two arrays hold information for all of the years. That's why I thought they should be added to each period of time, so that after the expand to panel-data, I calculate the `ibase`for each record (11x 3,2 million).

I don't need all of the columns for the regression analysis. In case it would dramatically improve the performance of the multiplying, we could stick to the rows (basically leaving out the geometry columns):

```
   gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('buildings_gid_seq'::regclass),
      gembez character varying(50),
      gemname character varying(50),
      krsbez character varying(50),
      krsname character varying(50),
      pv boolean,
      gr smallint,
      capac double precision,
      dist double precision,
      gemewz integer,
      n500 integer,
      ibase double precision,
      popden integer,
      instp smallint,
      b2000 double precision,
      b2001 double precision,
      b2002 double precision,
      b2003 double precision,
      b2004 double precision,
      b2005 double precision,
      b2006 double precision,
      b2007 double precision,
      b2008 double precision,
      b2009 double precision,
      b2010 double precision,
      ibase_id integer[],
      ibase_dist integer[],
      CONSTRAINT buildings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
    )
    WITH (
      OIDS=FALSE
```

### Solution Approach

I had the basic idea to create a second table `periods` containing the 11 different periods and multiply this table with the table `buildings`. Not sure how to implement this. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with R and don't use the [Database Interface for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/index.html), yet.

Working with PostgreSQL 9.5beta2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit and R x64 3.2.1

Comment: I could recommend to produce MRE (**minimal** reproducible example) as it encourage people to answer. Use `RPostgreSQL` and query only columns you need with `dbGetQuery`. Later manipulate with R `data.table` package, its syntax is quite analogous to SQL but much more modular and faster as it fits into memory and is well written in C. You can cross join your table with periods table to make row explosion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the Paneldata table by using an Cross JOIN with a temporary table t1, containing the periods.

```
CREATE TABLE public.t1
(
  period smallint
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);



CREATE TABLE paneldata AS
(SELECT * 
FROM t1 CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT gid, 
    gemname, 
    gembez, 
    krsname,
    krsbez,
    pv,
    gr,
    capac,
    dist,
    gemewz,
    n500,
    popden,
    instp
    FROM buildings) AS test
ORDER BY gid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, a panel data set is data in **long** format with repeating years for each record as the time column. Your current structure is in **wide** format. While R can transform this very large dataset, PostGreSQL can stack all years together in a union query with its engine and pass resultset into R. Do note some data types such as the geometry objects and arrays may not convert properly into R data types, so remove them or convert them to string/numeric types.

Below is such a SQL UNION query with stacked years. I am not quite sure what you mean with `ibase_id` and `ibase_dist` or the "multiplying" aspect but a `Year` column is added with corresponding `b` column. Have R script call it via the `RPostGreSQL` module.

```
import("RPostgreSQL")

# CREATE CONNECTION     
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "postgres",
                 host = "localhost", port = ####,
                 user = "username", password = "password")

strSQL <- "SELECT '2000' As year,  gid, gembez, gemname, krsbez,
                 krsname, pv, gr, capac, dist, gemewz, n500
                 popden, instp, b2000 As b, (1/ibase_dist) As ibase
           FROM public.buildings
           INNER JOIN
                (SELECT a.gid AS buildid, 
                        SUM(round(ST_Distance(
                                              ST_Transform(a.centroid, 31467),  
                                              ST_Transform(b.centroid, 31467)
                                  )::integer)) AS ibase_dist
               FROM buildings a
               LEFT JOIN buildings b 
                      ON ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(a.centroid, 31467), 
                                    ST_Transform(b.centroid, 31467), 500.0)
                    AND a.gid <> b.gid
               WHERE b.pv=True AND b.instp < a.instp
               GROUP BY a.gid) AS distSum
           ON public.buildings.gid = distSum.buildid
           WHERE public.buildings.instp = 2000

           UNION

           ...other SELECT statements for years 2001-2010..."              

# IMPORT QUERY RESULTSET INTO DATAFRAME
df <- dbGetQuery(con, strSQL)

# CLOSE CONNECTION
dbDisconnect(con)
```

But be sure you have the necessary [RAM](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html) for the operation of the big dataset. You might need to allocate memory accordingly. Alternatively, you can iteratively append each year's `SELECT` statement into a growing dataframe object instead of loading all at once.

```
# ...SAME CONNECTION SETUP AS ABOVE...

years = c('2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', 
          '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010')

# CREATES LIST OF YEAR DATA FRAME
dfList = lapply(years, 
                function(y) {
                # NOTICE CONCATENATION OF Y IN SELECT STATEMENT 
                strSQL <- paste0("SELECT '", y, "' As year,  gid, gembez, gemname, krsbez,
                                         krsname, pv, gr, capac, dist, gemewz, n500, 
                                         popden, instp, b", y, ", As b, (1/ibase_dist) As ibase, 
                                  FROM public.buildings
                                  INNER JOIN
                                    (SELECT a.gid AS buildid, 
                                          SUM(round(ST_Distance(
                                              ST_Transform(a.centroid, 31467),  
                                              ST_Transform(b.centroid, 31467)
                                          )::integer)) AS ibase_dist
                                     FROM buildings a
                                     LEFT JOIN buildings b 
                                     ON ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(a.centroid, 31467), 
                                                   ST_Transform(b.centroid, 31467), 500.0)
                                     AND a.gid <> b.gid
                                     WHERE b.pv=True AND b.instp < a.instp
                                     GROUP BY a.gid) AS distSum
                                  ON public.buildings.gid = distSum.buildid
                                  WHERE public.buildings.instp =", y)
                dbGetQuery(con, strSQL)                               
                })

# APPEND LIST OF DATA FRAMES INTO ONE LARGE DATA FRAME              
df <- do.call(rbind, dfList)

# REMOVE PREVIOUS LIST FOR MEMORY RESOURCES
rm(dfList)

# CLOSE CONNECTION
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: Besides `b`, there is another column, which should differ from period to period. It's the `ibase` column. At the moment `ibase` is still `NULL`. `ibase_id` is a string with years, `ibase_dist` a string with distances. The two strings are related and shall be mathematically combined to return an `double precision ibase` value. For each period, only the entrys of the arrays shall be considered, whose years were *BEFORE* the observated period of the panel-data. Right now, the two strings hold information for all of the years. That's why I thought they should be added to each period of time.

Comment: Can you post a data sample on how these `ibase` columns appear and desired results? This will better illustrate your explanation. Math operations can certainly be added to query but as mentioned by themselves complex Postgre types like arrays may not migrate into R dataframe types.

Comment: How do the arrays relate to current record? Do the distances in `ibase_dist` or gids in `ibase_id` correspond to a group the record belongs to or some identifier associated wth record?

Comment: The `gid`'s in the array belong to records of `buildings`, which are within a Radius of 500m around the `centroid`,the center of the obeject, AND have pv=TRUE (which implies that `dist`,`instdate`,`instp`,`capac`&`pvid` are `NOT NULL`).

I added the query which produced these arrays in my quesiton.

Comment: Much, much clearer. We can definitely join original query. Now, what do you mean "mathematically combined"?  Is `ibase` the sum of `ibase_dist` array elements for years before record's current year?

Comment: I want to try out different mathematical combinations. First, `ibase=Sum(1/s)` with `s` being the `ibase_dist` array elements for years before record's current year will do. (Later on I want to include other elements of the `gid`'s, like `capac`. That's why I wanted an array of the `gid`'s: to leave other combinations open)

Comment: See update where derived table is added, summing `ibase_dist` per criteria and then taking reciprocal in `ibase` calculation. Plus each select statement is condition on `instp` years. Not at all familiar with Postgre arrays and do not recommend multiple values in one column, you may be able to handle your needs with one-to-many joined table/view.

Comment: Not sure about the usage of `", y ,"` in the growing dataframe query.  
Is `"SELECT '", y, "'` intended like this, or are there `" "`, `, ,` or `' '` used by accident? Same for `b", y, ", As b` and `WHERE public.buildings.instp =", y `. I am asking, because the query returned multiple Errors.
  

I need to sum the reciprocal values of the distances. It's not the reciprocal value of the sum of the distances. But I fixed, using `Sum(1/(round(ST_Distance....)) AS ibase_dist` and deleting the `(1/...)` of  `(1/ibase_dist) AS ibase`